# Apply common scroll to all "float:right" elements

Tags: html, css, css-float

So I have this display, made for a portait-orientation view:

```
<div id="wrapper">

  <div class="to_right_on_landscape"></div>

  <div class="to_left_on_landscape"></div>

  <div class="to_right_on_landscape"></div>

</div>
```

In portrait orientation, each div displays full-width, on top of each other. That is good.

Now, when orientation is landscape, I want to throw that middle div to the left and the two others on the right, given this css (only applying in landscape orientation):

```
html, body, #wrapper {
  height: 100%;
}

.to_left_on_landscape {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
}

.to_right_on_landscape {
  width: 50%;
  float: right;
  overflow: auto; /* was naively hoping this would work */
}
```

Now my problem is: when my right divs' contents get too long in height, they grow longer than my left div. I would like these two div to have some sort of common `overflow:auto; height:100%` behavior, as if they were in the same div, which would display a nice scrollbar to browse the `float:right` elements while keeping the `float:left` one displayed on the left no matter how long the text on the right would be.

But I don't know how to achieve this without modifying the HTML, which would then break the design in the portrait orientation.

Comment: What about using FlexBox? http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decided to give up on the float property and used fixed position and 50% margins, like this:

```
html, body, #wrapper {
  height: 100%;
}

#wrapper {
  display: inline;
}

.to_left_on_landscape {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
}

.to_right_on_landscape {
  margin-left: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Flexbox is best approach for your requirement. Flexbox is css3 concept and it is compatible in all major browser.

you can check compatibility on this [link](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox).

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/v1yzdry0/)

```
    <style>
        .container {
          display: flex; /* or inline-flex */
        }
        .item {
          order: 2;
          flex:1;
          text-align:center;
          background-color:#f9f9f9;
          padding:10px;
          border:1px solid #CCC;
          text-align: justify;
          height:200px;
          overflow:auto;
        }

        @media screen and (orientation:portrait) {
            .container{
               flex-flow:column wrap;
            }
        }
        @media screen and (orientation:landscape) {
            .i2{
                order:1;
            }
        }
    </style>
```

And HTML Markup

```
    <div class="container">
        <div class="item">1</div>
        <div class="item i2">2</div>
        <div class="item">
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I don't get how to reproduce my thing though... [here's](https://jsfiddle.net/v1yzdry0/3/) how I see it looking myself. With the divs initially on top of each other, not side-by-side. Then in landscape I want it to look like it does, except that the right side should not visibly overflow under the left side, it should scroll.

Comment: Please check my updated answer again. I used flex.so please consider that. I checked your fiddle and you didn't use it

Comment: Yeah sorry, I'm considering it but everything I try to accomplish looks like utter crap... thought I would illustrate what I'm trying to do because [this](https://jsfiddle.net/v1yzdry0/10/) looks nothing like [it](https://jsfiddle.net/v1yzdry0/3/). The two right items don't stack on each other in landscape mode, and they take two-third of the space instead of half.